# Fetch organization name from FormRowModels

Tags: velocity, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Previously I was using separate email context for different subjects and I was doing something like this.

[image]

Now I want to fetch organization name from VM file only from formRowModels but this is giving an error.

```
${ctx.formRowModels.stream().filter(row -> row.getKey().contains("Organization"))}
```

[image]

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you're writing code in a VM file, you're not using Java but VTL (Velocity Template Language). You need to filter the desired value using a combination of `#foreach` & `#if #else` directives.

Example:

```
#foreach ($row in $ctx.yourList)
    #if ($row ... )
     doSomethingHere 
    #end
#end
```